# Spark how to find the columns where the two records have different values ( records sharing same primary key)

Tags: python, pandas, scala, apache-spark

Given a dataframe, I want to find , for the same primaryKeys combinations, what columns are not matched for the same primaryKeys.

For example, below dataframe, assuming primary Keys are `lastName + firstName`,
The first combination smith+john has `savingRate` not matched ( one is a valid 29.99, the other is 0);
The next combination chen+kodo, has `paymentRate` and `balance` not matched.

Technically speaking, for the same primary Keys, there should not duplicated records, however, for this dataframe, though the primary keys are just lastName + firstName, there are feature values that are not matched, and I want to find them out.

I am using Scala. Python solution is also accepted. What I can think of now is something like below, but it does not work :
The idea is , for each primaryKeys, find each feature average value and min value, if there is a feature whose min_value != avg_value, then this feature must have different values across all records which sharing same primary keys, then this feature is one of what I want to know.

Thanks!!

```
// assuming features are columns that are not primary keys

// for each feature, find its average value per primaryKeys
val avgCols = features_list.map(colName => avg(colName).cast("double").as("avg_" + colName))
val avgColsFull = df.groupBy(primaryKeys.head, primaryKeys.tail:_*).agg(avgCols.head, avgCols.tail:_*)

// for each feature, find its min value per primaryKeys
val minCols = features_list.map(colName => min(colName).cast("double").as("min_" + colName))
val minColsFull = df.groupBy(primaryKeys.head, primaryKeys.tail:_*).agg(minCols.head, minCols.tail:_*)

// a dataframe that primaryKeys and average/min feature values
val joinFull = (avgColsFull.join(minColsFull, primaryKeys, "inner")).drop(primaryKeys.toSeq:_*)
// get the column names
// joinFull header is like avg_savingRate, min_savingRate, avg_balance, min_balance
 joinFull.columns.map(c => { if(col("min_" + c.substring(4)) < col("avg_"+c.substring(4)))  println(c)} )  // <---- I guess this wont work but I need some help to fix it
```

[image]

Comment: Should the last record be filtered out? It is the same as the 4th record.

Comment: Once you have joinFull, you can add newColumn using withColumn on Dataframe for each column of feature list to compare min with avg of that column and set indicator 0 or 1